# Retrieving music from an old account

Tags: itunes, apple-id, itunes-store

I bought music from iTunes with my credit card, but it was my son’s iTunes account.  We shared a pc at that time. Can I retrieve my music and put it into my iTunes account?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot transfer the purchase.

However, you could use a computer with the other account and download all the music. You can transfer the files to wherever you'd like - but if you lose them again you'd still need the original files.

If you use a service like iTunes Match or Apple Music, adding these files to your iTunes Library after signing into your account should cause the music to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

No. Purchases are final. What you could do is see if family sharing allows you to share purchases across accounts.